# Background color on text, maintain left padding on line wrap

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a style that applies a background color to header text. This is simple enough by including an inline element within my header, but problems arise when there is a line wrap because the left padding is only applied to the first line of text. To solve this issue I am applying a left-border to my header tags, which properly maintains left padding during line wraps. However, I'm having serious issues matching the left-border height with the inline element background across browsers. I get it matched up in Chrome/Safari, and it's off in Firefox, etc. I've created a fiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/spidercoder/4KJn2/1/

My approach is:

HTML:

```
<h1><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1{
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 34px;
line-height: 44px;
border-left: 10px solid black;
padding: 8px 0 7px 0;} // This tweaks the height of the left-border

h1 span{
white-space: pre-wrap;
background: black;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;}
```

I've attempted several different approaches, but unfortunately nothing is working. This seems like a fairly simple effect to pull off, but I have been unable to properly match the height of the border with the span background across browsers, which ruins the effect.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to pull this off so it works across browsers? An approach that doesn't require the left-border would probably be best, so that we don't have to match element heights.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to the `span`:

```
box-shadow: 10px 0 0 black, -10px 0 0 black;
```

Or Just:

```
box-shadow: -10px 0 0 black;
```

Used this myself after finding it here:

http://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

There are many other methods by which this can be done listed there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and article link! I updated the fiddle with this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/spidercoder/4KJn2/6/. It's working great in everything except IE. In IE 11/Win 8.1, I'm getting a weird white line to the right of the shadow. Screenshot: http://imgur.com/x3awj0A. This appears to be a sub-pixel issue, as it appears/disappears as I resize the browser window. For example, it's fine at 900px, but at 901px the white line appears, then it's fine again at 902px. I've run into weird browser window size issues like this before but have never found an adequate solution. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like this has been reported twice to Microsoft, which has responded by saying to update ie11 and check back with them. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810756/ie-11-gap-between-element-background-and-its-box-shadow   One guy says the issue disappears depending on font size: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810522/unexpected-line-between-element-and-elements-shadow

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up on this. After much research and going down every possible path, I believe this is the best solution currently available. There is an issue with IE11 that causes a thin white line to appear between the shadow and the element, but that is a known IE bug, not a problem with the solution. For our project, we implemented this solution along with IE11 detection. For IE11, we're just making the headline a block element and having the black background extend the entire width of the element. Doesn't look quite as good, but that's IE's fault. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `span` is overflowing the `h1` by a pixel or so. One easy way around this is to add:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the `h1` style.

Answer (score 0):

Demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattSmith/4KJn2/2/).

HTML

```
<div class="padded-multiline">
    <h1><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.padded-multiline {
    line-height: 1.3; 
    padding: 2px 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid #000;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.padded-multiline h1 { 
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 4px 0 5px;
    color: #fff; 
    display: inline;
    margin: 0; 
}
.padded-multiline h1 span { 
    position: relative;
    left: -10px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting! Tried your solution and it works great, but running into similar height matching issues with the container in certain browsers. For example, if you remove the width: 400px; and resize the content area in IE11/Win 8.1, a misalignment occurs in the bottom-left corner at certain sizes. See screenshot here: http://imgur.com/iGzXeHw, and forked fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/spidercoder/4KJn2/7/

Comment: Do you still get that if you change `padding` on `.padded-multiline h1` to `4px 0 5px`?

Comment: I see what you mean now, resizing could potentially misalign the border background.

Answer (score 0):

Use margin-left instead of a border-left.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

h1 span {
    background: rgb(241,241,241);
    box-shadow: 15px 0 0 rgb(241,241,241), -15px 0 0 rgb(241,241,241);
  }
```

i made a demo http://jsfiddle.net/pa8J8/

Comment: Thanks for posting. Running in the same issue as JackArbiter's solution - works great in everything but IE. IE11 has a weird white line to the right of the shadow at certain window widths. Looks like this: http://imgur.com/x3awj0A

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-decoration-break: clone;` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break))

```html
<style>
  span {
    background-color: #bcbbbb;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #f48024;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font: 24px sans-serif;
    line-height: 2;
  }
</style>

<span>Stack<br />over<br />flow</span>

<hr />

<span style="box-decoration-break: clone;">Stack<br />over<br />flow</span>
```